# Does "USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller" mean my computer is USB3 compatible?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usb-3, device-manager

Using a tool to display my computers hardware properties, I can see that my computer has a "USB xHCI Compliant Host Controller".

Does this automatically mean, it is USB 3.0? Or could this also apply to a USB 2.0 connectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. [xHCI means USB 3.0 support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Host_Controller_Interface) (`red`). USB 2.0 is `enhanced host controller` (`green`)

[image]

The blue ones are USB 1.1 ([OpenHost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_%28USB,_Firewire%29#OHCI))

Some OEMs are indeed stupid and use USB 3.0 controllers, but use USB 2.0 ports (micro USB for example).

To see this, run a tool called [USB Device Tree Viewer](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html) and click on each listed port which has the entry `IsUserConnectable` (here the user can connect USb devices, some are internally used to attach devices like USB card readers) and look for `SupportedUSBProtocols` and if the entry `Usb300` has a `1 (yes)` set. Here not:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... what about this: http://superuser.com/questions/1071709/why-does-device-manager-show-intelr-usb-3-0-extensible-host-controller-0100?rq=1 ...?

Comment: what is your point?

Comment: My point is that in http://superuser.com/questions/1071709/why-does-device-manager-show-intelr-usb-3-0-extensible-host-controller-0100?rq=1 someone also had an xHCI controller, but only USB2 ports. I would like to find out if an xHCI controller means the computer has USB3 ports...

Comment: xHCI controller measn USB 3.0 CONTROLLER. If the manufacture only uses USB 2.0 (micro usb) it is his fault. Next time ask a proper question, you forget this important part of the question. I'll add this part to the answer *rolleyes*

Answer (score 1):

No, xHCI is designed to work with all speeds of USB devices.

There are devices that has an xHCI host controller but has only USB 2 ports.

On the other hands, on modern motherboards that has both USB 2 and 3 ports, the xHCI host controller is responsible for both types of them. You will also see that even those 12M "full-speed" devices, such as your keyboard and mouse, are attached to it as well. Although often there are fallback EHCI controller(s), I suppose they are for devices that somehow cannot be attached to an xHCI controller (which I have never seen).

In Linux this can been confirmed with `lsusb -t` or `lsusb.py`.

P.S. I believe the reason we often (wrongly) consider `xHCI = USB3` is because 5Gbps (or 10Gbps) is not supported in EHCI, and xHCI is currently the only/latest standard we have for USB host controllers that supports USB 3.x speeds. But that doesn't mean it is wrong/stupid/impossible for a device to have an xHCI controller but only USB 2 ports.

Comment: @magicandre1981 there's nothing stupid of a manufacturer to have an xHCI host controller (improved standard, better/more updated drivers...) but have only USB 2 ports. It's merely stupid for a user to determine which kind of USB ports a device has by looking up which type of host controller it has.