# How do I identify is a thumb drive is a USB 2 or a USB 3 in Windows if there is no markings on the thumb drive to identify it

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a thumb drive and it has a black colored USB port. I plug into a computer that only have USB 2 port. At first, it can be identify. I did a format and suddenly, the device cannot be recognized.

May I know how I can tell if the thumb drive is a USB 2 or USB 3, given that it does not have a blue colored USB port and there are no markings or identifier to tell if the thumb drive is a USB 2 or 3.

I also notice that under the Eject thumb drive option, I notice it label as 'USB 3 check!'. This made me wonder if the thumb drive is a USB 3 device.

Please enlighten me.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to post a picture of this thumb drive? What brand/model is it?

Comment: You could try to test the READ/WRITE speeds and compare them to USB 2.0 and 3.0 specs :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying USB connection speed (USB 3 or USB 2?)](http://superuser.com/questions/478184/verifying-usb-connection-speed-usb-3-or-usb-2)

Answer (score 2):

While they have the same footprint, the USB 3.0 connector has an extra set of 5 pins

[image].
It is also supposed to be blue by specification I believe.

Your drive is probably USB 2.0