# Data Transfer in Windows 10 is dead slow

Tags: windows-10, data-transfer

I installed Windows 10 on New Acer Laptop. Initially data transfer on windows 10 between internal hdd and external hdd was above 130MB/sec but now it is rarely touching 25MB/sec.

I looked on forums but could get any answer. On my home computer which is Windows 7 transfer rate is above 120 . What might be the cause of this slowness

Comment: You probably don't have write-caching enabled.

Comment: checked it's enabled

Comment: Is it enabled for both your internal and external HDDs?

Comment: External drive was set for Quick removal , i changed it to Better Performance but still not effect it hardly touches 25MB

Comment: Ok here what i tested, I copied 3gb file in C: Drive and transfer rate is above 100MB but on D: drive it is 25MB

Comment: Also this is probably a silly suggestion, but make sure your hard drive is connected to a USB 3.0 port (I'm assuming your computer is USB 3.0 enabled since you mentioned speeds over 120 MiB/s) and try a different USB 3.0 port if you have more than one. Make sure [your HDD is connected to your computer in SuperSpeed mode by testing the connection using USB Device Tree Viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/478184/verifying-usb-connection-speed-usb-3-or-usb-2/700326#700326). Also try using a different USB 3.0 cable if you have one lying around.

Comment: Are C and D both partitions on your external hard drive?

Comment: Yes dear , i thought of same thing of changing cables so i changes the cable. But it didnt work. And yes cable is connected to USB 3.0 even the tool you recommended confirmed. i dont know maybe this is some windows 10 issue.

C is Windows drive and D is local drive. and are both on same hdd

Comment: Bear in mind that the cable has to be USB 3.0 compatible (usually thicker than USB 2.0 cables and has a blue connector at one end). Did USB Device Tree Viewer confirm that the HDD was connected in **SuperSpeed** mode though? Because it's possible that it's connected in **High-Speed** mode, which is the same as USB 2.0 mode. You mentioned that you changed the HDD mode to **Better Performance** but also make sure that [the check-box for write-caching is enabled](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jQgHS.png) (if it shows).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36940/discussion-between-omipenguin-and-vinayak).