# Pathetic write speed to USB 3.0 flash drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, usb-flash-drive, flash

My new Patriot 128Gb rage 2 flash drive is slow as molasses. It's spec'd to 150 Mb/s write speed, actually delivered 68 Mb/s the first time i backed up 1.45 Gb on it. That's ...adequate. But since the first time or two, it's been writing consistently down around 0.01 Mb/s, on a USB 3.0 port on my Win 10 MSi laptop.

The flash is already formatted NTFS, and i already used Device Manager to set the Policy to "Better performance" and rebooted, with no change. It seems to perform OK on other computers, and other flash drives work ok on this one. Right now it's about 55% full, and while it's writing, Task Manager shows about 50% "Disc usage". Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm that the device is registered as the proper speed for a USB 3.2 Gen 1 device (I.e USB 3.0)?

Comment: Registered how? 
(I can confirm it was writing at 68 Mb/s first time or two, and now, without me changing any settings, it's down around 0.01 Mb/s consistently.)

Comment: There are tools which will identify how fast the device is, looking to make sure, it identifies as Superspeed+ (I believe that’s correct and 3.0).

Comment: Honestly i don't care much what a tool says, the only metric that matters to me is how long it takes per Gb to back up my external HDD - and i don't think it should be "hours". Heck, it was just a few minutes when i started using this thing. What changed?

Comment: The tool would identify if the device was being registered as a USB 3 device.  This would eliminate some possibilities.  It’s a diagnostic step that would be helpful.  [USB Device Tree Viewer](https://superuser.com/questions/478184/verifying-usb-connection-speed-usb-3-or-usb-2/700326#700326) would be one of those tools.

Comment: Can you also specify what kind of data you’re writing to the drive? Are you just copying files? How big are the files, and how many of them?

Comment: What kind of data? It's a mixed bag, a folder containing 293 folders, 3,044 files. One of six i can back up to an external HDD in about 20 minutes (all six).

The main question at this point is, why was it so fast (avg. 68 Mb/s) the first 2 times, and so slow since then (0.01 Mb/s), and why is it still fast writing on another laptop?